# Jquery .focus() working in FF but not in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I am working on an AJAX live search on my site and for its navigation through the search results i am using up/down arrow keys. This works fine on FF as it navigates through all the results by shifting the focus. But in chrome it seems that the focus is not getting shifted at all.

The code which shifts the focus is..

```
$("#counter").val(foc);
var idname = '#'+foc;
$(idname).focus();
```

Comment: Need some more context, can you post a fiddle?

Comment: your version of chrome?

Comment: actually cannot.. coz its quite complex.. i've just posted a part which shifts ths focus dynanically on keyup

Comment: @Jai my chrome version- 26.0

Comment: Have you checked if any elements get the same `id`s? It breaks some stuff on Chrome.

Comment: needs more context. if you could post the event handlers and some html it would help out a lot

Comment: @Sriniwas It's always possible to create a fiddle. We're talking about the client side so you can always copy the final html with the search results sent from the server. Adding the eventhandlers to that shouldn't be that complex either. Without more code it's pretty hard to find out...

Comment: @MarcelGwerder it has many loops and the data is coming from a database.. it will take time for me to create a fiddle.. can u pls suggest me a way to work with focus on chrome??

Comment: As I said the database and loops don't matter. Just copy the result html from your developer tools in chrome. [`focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) is also not usable on all elements, this may differ between browsers. So we need at least the html element you try to "focus".

Comment: here is the fiddle u wanted.. http://jsfiddle.net/jpsj7/

Comment: Please add some search results...